# Compartir información entre 2 servidores SQL de forma automática

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo: 
 - La tabla "tabla_1" en el equipo A (SQL Server)
 - La tabla "tabla_2" en el equipo B (SQL Server)

Necesito que cada vez que se inserte un valor en la tabla "tabla_1", copiarlo y pegarlo en la tabla "tabla_2" automáticamente.

He pensado en usar un trigger, pero no sé como conectarme desde comando con el SGBD SQL del equipo B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de hacer nada, tienes que habilitar la conexión remota de tu SQL Server, os dejo un link [aquí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHDbkgpXwuE) sobre como hacerlo

Para empezar vamos a la pestaña de 'Linked Servers' y hacemos clic derecho para crear uno nuevo.

[image: 1][image: 2]

---

Rellenamos con la ip y el puerto del SQL Server al que nos queremos linkar (importante la coma y el espacio entre al IP y el Puerto) y hacemos clic en el radial de "SQL Server".

[image: 4]

---

Vamos a la pestaña de 'Security' y tras haber hecho clic en el radial de "Be made using this security contest" rellenamos los recuadros con el nombre de usuario y la contraseña.

NOTA: El usuario tiene que existir en la base de datos a la que nos queremos conectar, y tendremos el mismo acceso que este.

[image: 5]

---

Una vez hecho esto, los servidores ya están conectados entre sí, y puedes hacer consultas transact-SQL desde un server al otro.

Ejemplo:

```
select * from [192.168.22.151, 1433].master.sys.databases
```

[image: 6]

---

Para hacerlo de forma automática hay 2 opciones, hacerla mediante jobs con el Agente de SQL o con SQLcmd. Al tener la SQL Express (la gratuita) no dispongo del SQL Server Agent, por lo que voy a usar SQLcmd.

Lo primero es guardar la sentencia que queremos que se ejecute de forma automática en un archivo .sql

Creamos un archivo .bat y metemos lo siguiente:

```
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -E -i "nuestroArchivoSQL.sql"
```

Nota: Para crear un archivo bat, accedemos a la ubicación donde queremos guardarlo mediante el cmd (cd "ubicación") y escribimos

```
notepad "nombre de archivo.bat"
```

Una vez temos el archivo .bat, vamos al panel del programador de tareas de Windows 10, creamos una tarea nueva que ejecute el archivo .bat y especificamos cada cuanto queremos que lo ejecute

Abrimos el programador de tareas

[image: tar]

Creamos una tarea nueva

[image: fre]

Añadimos un nuevo desencadenante (cada cuanto queremos que se ejecute)

[image: gtr]

[image: fed]

Creamos una nueva accion

[image: gtr]

La acción va a ser la que ejecute nuestro archivo .bat

[image: llp]

Espero que les haya servido de ayuda.

Salu2

Comment: Puedes usar esta guia https://www.sqlshack.com/es/como-crear-y-configurar-un-servidor-enlazado-en-sql-server-management-studio/

Comment: y para tus querys te recoemiendo uses openquery algo asi:  SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([SERVIDOR_B],'select * from TABLA')

Comment: Gracias por la guía, ha sido de ayuda :p ¿Qué diferencia hay entre usar OPENQUERY y no usarlo? @Manny